# AWS SDK connection - How is this working?? (Beginner)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on my AWS cert and I'm trying to figure out how the following bit of js code works:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

// Create an S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

// Create a bucket and upload something into it
var bucketName = 'node-sdk-sample-' + uuid.v4();
var keyName = 'hello_world.txt';

s3.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, function() {
  var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: 'Hello'};
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
  });
});
```

This code successfully loads a txt file containing the words "Hello" in it. I do not understand how this ^ can identify MY AWS account. It does! But how! It somehow is able to determine that I want a new bucket inside MY account, but this code was taken directly from the AWS docs. I don't know how it could figure that out....

Answer (score 4):

As per [Class: AWS.CredentialProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CredentialProviderChain.html#defaultProviders-property), the AWS SDK for JavaScript looks for credentials in the following locations:

```
AWS.CredentialProviderChain.defaultProviders = [
  function () { return new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS'); },
  function () { return new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AMAZON'); },
  function () { return new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials(); },
  function () {
    // if AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI is set
      return new AWS.ECSCredentials();
    // else
      return new AWS.EC2MetadataCredentials();
  }
]
```

- Environment Variables (useful for testing, or when running code on a local computer)
- Local credentials file (useful for running code on a local computer)
- ECS credentials (useful when running code in Elastic Container Service)
- Amazon EC2 Metadata (useful when running code on an Amazon EC2 instance)

It is highly recommended to **never store credentials within an application**. If the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance and a **role has been assigned to the instance**, the SDK will automatically [retrieve credentials from the instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials).

The next best method is to store credentials in the `~/.aws/credentials` file.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But where is this ^ code getting the credentials. It somehow takes this code and creates a bucket. I'm taking the code from right here: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/ where they obviously are not using my personal account. But that's where it's going...

Comment: Where are you running your code? On an Amazon EC2 instance? On your own computer?

Comment: I'm running on my own computer. I DO see AWS credentials in my root directory... is that where this is coming from? How are you supposed to plan for deployment when AWS SDK randomly pulls things from your file system?

Comment: It's allll the way at the bottom in .aws. Is it seriously going all the way out of my project to grab that...? That seems like a terrible design. How are you supposed to develop locally and ensure it will work the same way in production?

Comment: In production, if you are running on an Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned role, there is **no credentials file**. The SDK automatically retrieves the credentials through EC2 instance metadata. So, a credentials file is only necessary on a non-EC2 system (but an also be used on EC2 if desired).

Comment: That is interesting. Thanks for clarifying. Do you have any useful articles on that? Still trying to figure out how all this stuff connects in the Amazon environment. It's surprisingly sparse on this topic

Comment: It varies by SDK. For node, see: [Setting Credentials in Node.js - AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html)

Comment: The AWS SDKs will use (as one of its search locations) the credentials that you setup for the CLI. If you do not like this for production reasons, then you will find specific APIs in the SDK for loading credentials from a source (location) that you prefer. For production code in the cloud, look at using either IAM roles or AWS Secrets Manager https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/ . There are of course many methods to chose from. However, make security of your credentials a priority.